# Facebook JavaScript SDK sources?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, requirejs, facebook-javascript-sdk

In https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/requirejs/v2.3  the file structure is the following:

```
- project/
    - index.html
    - scripts/
       - main.js
       - require.js
       - fb.js
```

Where does one get **fb.js** and **main.js** from ? I have been unable to find the sources of the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are your own files. Examples for both files are in the section "Adding a shim to the Facebook SDK". There are two code parts, one for main.js and one for fb.js:

main.js

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    'facebook' : {
      exports: 'FB'
    }
  },
  paths: {
    'facebook': '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk'
  }
})
require(['fb']);
```

fb.js

```
define(['facebook'], function(){
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    version    : 'v2.3'
  });
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Tell me if it works, i´ve never used RequireJS, i only know the basics. Never will use it though, CommonJS with Webpack or Browserify is so much better :)

Comment: Yes it did :-) Now the FB variable is finally initialised.

Comment: perfect. please don´t forget to set the answer flag on my answer :)